# web api windows authentication unauthorized on foxxl

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I hope somebody can help me with the following issue, I have been working on a mvc4 web api running on .net 4.0 and ef code first. I am trying to use basic authentication in combination with the authorize attribute. It works on my Azure trial and also on Localhost but i cant get it to work on foxxl hosting and it keeps asking me for credentials which seem to be invalid when i try it on the foxxl hosting. For testing i am not using https so but this will be included in release version.

Here is some sample code that i have added for basic authentication:

**Web config**

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="KlantenBestand.BasicAuthHttpModule, KlantenBestand"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

**TestController**

```
        [Authorize]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {

            String name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, name);
        }
```

**BasicAuthHttpModule**

```
public class BasicAuthHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private const string Realm = "KlantenBestand";
        private static KlantenBestandContext db = new KlantenBestandContext();

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            // Register event handlers
            context.AuthenticateRequest += OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
            context.EndRequest += OnApplicationEndRequest;
        }

        private static void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
        {
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            }
        }

        private static bool CheckPassword(string username, string password)
        {
            var company = db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAdress.Equals(username));

            return company != null && company.Password.Equals(Md5Hash(password));
        }

        private static bool AuthenticateUser(string credentials)
        {
            bool validated = false;
            try
            {
                var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
                credentials = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(credentials));

                int separator = credentials.IndexOf(':');
                string name = credentials.Substring(0, separator);
                string password = credentials.Substring(separator + 1);

                validated = CheckPassword(name, password);
                if (validated)
                {
                    var identity = new GenericIdentity(name);
                    SetPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(identity, null));
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                // Credentials were not formatted correctly.
                validated = false;

            }
            return validated;
        }

        private static void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (authHeader != null)
            {
                var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);

                // RFC 2617 sec 1.2, "scheme" name is case-insensitive
                if (authHeaderVal.Scheme.Equals("basic",
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                    authHeaderVal.Parameter != null)
                {
                    AuthenticateUser(authHeaderVal.Parameter);
                }
            }
        }

        // If the request was unauthorized, add the WWW-Authenticate header 
        // to the response.
        private static void OnApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            if (response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
                    string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public static string Md5Hash(string password)
        {
            MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            //compute hash from the bytes of text
            md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));

            //get hash result after compute it
            byte[] result = md5.Hash;

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits
                //for each byte
                strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            return strBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
I also tryed adding the authentication lines to my web.config because my hosting said this would solve the issue. But when i do that and run it localhost it gives me the following error: **This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".**

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="KlantenBestand.BasicAuthHttpModule, KlantenBestand"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

It is set to Windows Authentication. You will need to remove that line.

Comment: Yeah good point! That was one of the things which i didnt do correctly, but unfortunately even after removing that line it doesnt let me Authenticate on my Hosting. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Need more info. Are you still getting 401? If so, what do you get in the response. Capture the traffic using Fiddler and post the request and response messages.

Comment: Oke i made the Request with Fiddler running and it just gives me a 401 due invalid credentials. Then it pops up the Dialog again to enter username and password.

I have also tryed adding the following section in the web.config because my hosting is telling me that this would solve the issue but  when i run that on localhost it tells me the following:

Comment: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Comment: That section should work in IIS. In local, you will most probably use IIS Express and hence that error. BTW, you should actually set <basicAuthentication enabled="false"/>. Give it a try in local IIS or the one given by your hosting provider.

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks that did the job!